# How can I use paper_trail gem to store creator details?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise, paper-trail-gem

I have a rails (4.1.6) Blog app that contains Posts. It uses devise for users and I am in the process of integrating the [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem for versioning.

Prior to integrating with paper_trail, each Post had a belongs_to :user, which was filled with the current_user at the top of create: `@post = Post.new(user: current_user)`. However, since paper_trail stores the creator of items, I would like to use @post.originator instead to access the creator.

In this blog app, only a signed in user can create posts. In my validator, I need to check that @post.originator exists, but while validating my post, the originator is blank (presumably because paper_trail does not save the paper trail data until the post is created in the database).

So, when I create a post and the validator runs, using originator instead, I get an error that the post cannot be created since there is no originator.

The options I see are:

1. Validate user_signed_in? in the controller actions, and *not* validate for creator (user/originator) in the model
2. Create a redundant user field in all my models to store the creator of a post, and use that for validation
3. Do both 1 and 2
4. Somehow *(how?)* make the paper_trail provide the model's originator and use that in validation

I suspect the ideal approach is #3 or at least #1 or #2, but I wanted to check if there was any way to achieve #4.

Thanks
Anand